# Put Elements in a Group to re position in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey is there any way to put all Shape, Text and Buttons in something like a group so I only have to reposition the group?
I made a little Quiz with a shape as Background, Text on the Top and 2 Buttons with True and False. Now I want to put the whole Quiz a few pixels to the right but don't want to reposition every text, button, shape etc. I couldn't find anything by research and have tried anything. Pls Help [the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOCUy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to reposition the parent div

Comment: Thank you! I tried it before but doesnt work as I expected. I think I did something wrong before!